# Jquery trigger click event based on anchor tag name property

Tags: jquery

I have an anchor tag

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" rel="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" role="button" tabindex="0" track="click:create_group_button" name="create_group_button" data-original-title="Create Group"><i class="fa fa-plus" tabindex="-1"></i> Group</a>
```

This is generated dynamically, as you can see there is no id property available.
I need to trigger click event on document ready on this anchor tag like

```
$("nameoftheanchor").click();
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `$("body").on("a[name='create_group_button']", "click", function(){})`?

Comment: if the name is unique, you can access it like this `$('a[name="create_group_button"]')`, you can precise it if you need more attribute values, like `$('a[name="create_group_button"][role="button"]')`

Answer (score 1):

You can select by anchor and its name using this code in jquery

> `a[name='create_group_button']`

```js
$("a[name='create_group_button']").click(function(){
  alert('here');

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" rel="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" role="button" tabindex="0" track="click:create_group_button" name="create_group_button" data-original-title="Create Group"><i class="fa fa-plus" tabindex="-1"></i> Group</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not always necessary to use ID selector in jquery to trigger any event.

```
$('a[name="create_group_button"]').click(function (//use this to write the logic) {})
```

Answer (score 0):

To trigger a click event:.

```
$("a[name='create_group_button']").trigger("click");
```